# mongoDB query modifiers check

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i have this code that i want to fetch data from mongoDB  with query modifiers such as the 'limit' and 'Orders'

```
        let data;
        if (obj.search && obj.sortBy && obj.limit){
            data = await this.UsersModel.find()
                .or([{name: obj.search}, {email: obj.search}])
                .sort({[obj.sortBy]: 'asc'})
                .skip(0)
                .limit(parseInt(obj.limit));
        }
        else {
            if(!obj.search && !obj.sortBy && !obj.limit)
                return "No users for such criteria";
            if(!obj.search){
                data = await this.UsersModel.find({})
                    .sort({[obj.sortBy]: 'asc'})
                    .skip(0)
                    .limit(parseInt(obj.limit));

            }
            else if(!obj.sortBy){
                data = await this.UsersModel.find()
                    .or([{name: obj.search}, {email: obj.search}])
                    .skip(0)
                    .limit(parseInt(obj.limit));
            }
            else if(!obj.limit){
                data = await this.UsersModel.find()
                    .or([{name: obj.search}, {email: obj.search}])
                    .sort({[obj.sortBy]: 'asc'})
            }
        }
```

can i   check for these query modifiers ( "or", "limit", "sort" ...etc ) with another solution without **use multi if condition** ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you ever considered using aggregate for list controllers? With that approach, you can create function that will read query parameters and generate aggregate phases such as sort, limit/skip, match and return them as array, then just spread that array inside aggregate. That is the approach I use, not saying it is correct one, but it does take a lot of hard coding work of your hands.

Comment: @jscode jscode Why not use query and projection params in `find` method for this.